# First REST Spring application

Tags: java, spring, rest

I m trying to create my first Spring application which is a simple REST webservice.
I want to make EVERY responses to be JSON (in the header) and I dont know how to make it in ONE time, I mean not in all my controller methods, like a config files or something else.

This is my code :

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/something/{nom}/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User hi(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable String nom) {
        return new User(id, nom);
    }
}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Try adding `@ResponseBody` after `@RestController`.

Comment: Have you tried accessing on this ? The User should be parsed to JSON String by jackson by default.

Comment: @KeithEnlow That wouldn't help; `@RestController` already automatically implies `@ResponseBody`, it's not necessary to add it explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is correct. Since you are using Spring 4 and the annotation @RestController there's no need of using @ResponseBody.

In case you are not getting a JSON as return, please check if you have included Jackson Mapper dependency in your project.

You can do that by adding this on your pom.xml (presuming you are using Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

By adding this dependency, Spring will be able to parse your object properly.